# How can I perform a regex match and output the matches

Tags: linux, command-line, regex, wget

I'm performing a link check on a site from a list of urls, and the only way I can think of is using wget: `wget --server-response -i inputfile 2> output` and then further parse the header response. This outputs a relatively large file for a large list, and I only want to know if a 404 is present. A typical response looks something like:

```
--2017-03-28 19:14:39--  https://www.example.com/foo/bar
Reusing existing connection to www.example.com:443.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 
  HTTP/1.1 404 NotFound
<snip>
```

How can I perform a regex match from the output by wget for each url (from stderr), and if a 404 is present output the url which I can then redirect to a file so I am left with a file that has a list of 404's? (Please don't suggest using curl, the site is unfortunately set up to return `METHOD NOT ALLOWED`.

Comment: your title is far too much of an oversimplification of what you are actually asking

Comment: @barlop all titles are simplifications of problems: their purpose is a summary. Feel free to make an edit

Comment: if you included in your question some sample example output then it'd help.  Do you mean you want to  download webpage at url matching a regex,  and append 404 yielding URLs to a file?

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
#!/bin/bash

URLLIST=/path/to/file

for each in `cat $URLLIST`
do
   IS404=`wget -S "$each" -O /dev/null 2>&1 | grep "HTTP/1.1 404" | wc -l`

    if [ $IS404 -gt 0 ]
    then
        echo $each
    fi
done
```

I've only partially tested the above, but the key line, starting with IS404 does a wget for each URL (because its in a for each loop), discards the output, redirects standard output - thats what 2>&1 does - and thus the headers (thanks to -S) to stdout, where it then counts the number of 404 responses.  If one or more is found, it prints the URL.

Comment: Am I right in assuming this will prevent wget from reusing the same connection (thus dramatically slowing down the run-through)

Comment: It will not reuse the connection, however I do not believe -i does either (I could be wrong here).  There  are, of-course other ways to speed it up - I would not recommend something so naive, but, for example adding an "&" to the magic line will request every url in parellel.  [ t could be practical to write something more sophisticated that launches requests in batches - but yes, this is still inefficient for the server].

Comment: If you are needing something more complex, you really should fall back to using Curl, and work through the problem with "METHOD NOT ALLOWED" - it must technically be possible.    Also, you could possibly use a HEAD request rather then a get request with CURL = lot less output.

Comment: may be helpful to show the output in your answer

Comment: Output is a list of urls (which match 404 errors) one per page. No input was given, so no testing or output given ! (But someone else is welcome to test and tweek)

Comment: would you also benefit from using this kind of thing `-t 1 -T 5 -w 3`  to stop it hammering away.  
 -t,  --tries=NUMBER            set number of retries to NUMBER (0 unlimits).
-T,  --timeout=SECONDS         set all timeout values to SECONDS.
-w,  --wait=SECONDS            wait SECONDS between retrievals.

Answer (score 0):

**SORRY, initially I missed the "do not suggest curl" caution**. But you can still get something out of this post...

The way to do this is to use *curl*. If you get the reply *METHOD NOT ALLOWED*, the very same reply **must** contain a list of allowed methods. You might perhaps post it. Sometimes the *GET* method is disallowed, while the *HEAD* method is allowed; other times, it is the vice versa. The only way to know is to check the reply. My **guess** is that you tried the *GET* method, and automatically jumped to the conclusion that the *HEAD* method (*i.e.*, download only headers) is equally disallowed. It is not necessarily so, sometimes administrators prohibit GET to avoid overloading their limited connection resources, but they will allow HEAD. No way to know *a priori*.

*curl*'s advantages:

1. *curl* can be be told to download only the header, thus dropping the useless (in this case) download of the real page; just try:

   ```
   curl -I http://www.debian.org
   ```
2. *curl* automatically keeps a connection open for a default time (900 secs, I *think*):

   ```
   # curl -v http:://www.debian.org -I www.debian.org
     ......
     * Connection #0 to host www.debian.org left intact
   ```

   This is the default option, but, just to err on the safe side, [the Manual](https://linux.die.net/man/1/curl) states that you *may* use, if you wish, the *--keepalive* option.

To speed things further, you may wish to parallelize *curl*:

```
URL_LIST=$(cat inputfile)
echo $URL_LIST | xargs -n 1 -P 8 -I{} bash -c 'curl -I {} 2>1 | grep 404 &>/dev/null ; [ $? ] && echo {}'
```

This passes the URL names one by one (*-n 1*) up to a maximum of 8 **in parallel** (*-P 8*) to the following command, which prints the URL name if and only if a *404* code is found. The option *-I{}* tells xargs where to place the selected URL name. All output is discarded because all that is needed is the exit code of the last command, *grep*.

There are many more adaptations possible, depending on your specific needs: the list of options of *curl* is humongous.

Comment: I said, I can't use curl.

Comment: @user3791372 You said it, but you did not explain it, nor did you investigate the above.

Answer (score -1):

You could install powershell 
https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell

Then you can easily write a powerfull script that checks and does stuff like email if an url is down: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18500832/script-to-check-the-status-of-a-url

```
Foreach($Uri in $URLList) {
  $error.Clear()

  $time = Measure-Command { $request = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri } 2>$null

  if ($error.Count -eq 0) {
    $time.TotalMilliseconds
  } else {
    $error[0].Exception.Response
  }
}
```

Comment: Problem with this response is that it (a) does not answer the question - and use wget as requested, (b) is Windows centric and requires additional software, (c) Outputs not only 404's but any 4xx or 5xx responses

Comment: there's a #linux tag for a reason!

Comment: @davidgo (a) "and the only way I can think of is using wget" makes me believe wget is not the only possible solution, he just want's something that works. (b) the software is open source, cross platform and simple to install (c) $error will contain the response code, it's trivial to check against.

Comment: @user3791372 powershell is not windows specific, it works just fine under linux.